# Symfony2.1 FOSUserBundle overriding validation

Tags: symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

i have problems overriding the form validation.

I have overridden the user class and the RegisterFormType class. In the RegisterFormType class i used the setDefaultOptions function to use an other validation group

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Clickstorm\Geruest\UserBundle\Entity\User',
        'intention' => 'register',
        'validation_groups' => array('register')
    ));
}
```

But when i submit the form the default validation is executed. But what confuses me the most is that when i tried to override the validation by create an own validation.xml file the validation was triggered twice (the error messages where schon twice).

Any idea about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right solution. But it works when overriding the validation_groups in the config file.